# Simple Python Error

Tags: python

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in range(len(x)):
  if i > 5:
    x.remove(i)
print (x)
```

When I execute this code, I get x = [1,2,3,4,5,9], when I was attempting to take out everything above 5. What would make this accurate?

Comment: When you do range(9), it goes 0-8.

Comment: Note that `x.remove()` does **not remove the index** but the value. `x.remove(6)` removes the *value* at index 7. You are mixing indices and values here.

Comment: if you only need to create a list conditions, in your case above 5, you can simply use boolean expressions.

Comment: like make x a numpy array, x = numpy.array(x) and then say x = x[x>5]

Comment: @Srivatsan This only works with `numpy` arrays. Not everybody uses numpy.

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic solution in Python for this kind of problems is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Try this:

```
[e for e in x if e <= 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your indices range from 0 through to 8:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> list(range(len(x)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

but `list.remove()` removes items *by value*.

You'd have to do:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] > 5:
        x.remove(i)
```

instead, but that'd only remove the *first* such value. Moreover, this will end up *skipping* indices, eventually ending with a `IndexError`.

Because you are removing items, the values *following* the one you removed all shift up one step. The value `7` is now at index `5` (it was at `6`):

```
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> x.index(7)
6
>>> x.remove(6)
>>> x.index(7)
5
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

but the *loop* still keeps on counting. The loop goes from `i = 5` to `i = 6`, where we now have the number `8`, having missed the number `7`. And the list is now 1 element shorter but the `range()` was already calculated at the start of the loop. We'll get an `IndexError` when we run out of list but not out of indices.

When removing items from a list, it is far easier to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter instead, in a list comprehension:

```
x = [i for i in x if i <= 5]
```

This *keeps* all elements that are 5 or smaller, and because it builds a new list, you don't run into the resizing existing list problem.

Comment: The idea of values shifting down makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given this list:

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

If you just want the list elements until a condition is met, use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> list(takewhile(lambda e: e<=5, x))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To filter the elements where each element meets a condition, use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> list(filter(lambda e: e<=5, x))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Or, use a list comprehension as Óscar López or Martijn Pieters have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In Range you ve to remember about Zero indexing.

```
range(N) -> start from Zero to N-1
range(4) returns [0, 1, 2, 3]
or
range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers
```

So, you can fixed your snippet by changing the range:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> for i in range(1, len(x) + 1):
...     if i > 5:
...         x.remove(i)
...
>>> print x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

But this case was lucky because your list was in sequence else it won't give you the right answer.

Here is just another options:

```
>>> x = [9,2,3,4,1,5,6]
>>> y = sorted(x)
>>> y[0:x.index(5)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```